# convert an object of arrays into individual objects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object of arrays, I want to create individual objects from those array values,

```
"SUMMARY_TABLE": {
                "PRODUCT_CODE": [
                    123,
                    123,
                    123,
                    123,
                    123
                ],
                "TYPE": [
                    "CURRENT",
                    "OPTIMAL",
                    "MINIMUM",
                    "MAXIMUM",
                    "FUTURE"
                ],
                "LOT_SIZE": [
                    268.0,
                    268.0,
                    268.0,
                    268.0,
                    500.0
                ]}
```

above is the response Im getting. I want to create 5 individual objects from this data like

```
{
"product_code": 123,
"type": "current",
"lot_size" : 268
}
```

similarly using values in the arrays at other indexes.
I am trying this but it is not giving me the result I need. k contains the key name and array of values, like ['Product_Code', Arr(5)]

```
const data = Object.entries(selectedProductDetails.SUMMARY_TABLE).map(
    (k, v) => {
      let obj = {};
      return {
        ...obj, k: k[i++]
      }
    });
```

I would appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` and create a new `object` for each element.

Here's an example:

```
const summaryTable = {
  "PRODUCT_CODE": [
      123,
      123,
      123,
      123,
      123
  ],
  "TYPE": [
      "CURRENT",
      "OPTIMAL",
      "MINIMUM",
      "MAXIMUM",
      "FUTURE"
  ],
  "LOT_SIZE": [
      268.0,
      268.0,
      268.0,
      268.0,
      500.0
  ]
};

const individualObjects = summaryTable.PRODUCT_CODE.map((productCode, index) => {
  return {
    product_code: productCode,
    type: summaryTable.TYPE[index].toLowerCase(),
    lot_size: summaryTable.LOT_SIZE[index]
  }
});

console.log(individualObjects);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this was very simple to follow

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all the values of one of the arrays stored in `table` to be able to get the index, then iterate over the keys & values of `table` to get every property. This makes it so if `table` changes, you don't need to modify this code.

```js
const table = {
  PRODUCT_CODE: [123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
  TYPE: ["CURRENT", "OPTIMAL", "MINIMUM", "MAXIMUM", "FUTURE"],
  LOT_SIZE: [268.0, 268.0, 268.0, 268.0, 500.0],
};

const entries = Object.entries(table);
const data = table.TYPE.map((_, i) => entries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  acc[key] = value[i];
  if (key === "TYPE") acc[key] = value[i].toLowerCase(); // if you need this, keep it
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(data);
```